# Use of index in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Suppose I have 2 types of nodes :Server and :Client.

```
(Client)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(Server)
```

I want to find the Female clients connected to some Server ordered by age.

I did this

```
Match (s:Server{id:"S1"})<-[:CONNNECTED_TO]-(c{gender:"F"}) return c order by c.age DESC
```

Doing this, all the Client nodes linked to my Server node are traversed to find the highest age.
Is there a way to index the Client nodes on gender and age properties to avoid the full scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create an index on `:Client(gender)`, as follows:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Client(gender);
   ```

   However, your particular query will probably benefit more from creating an index on `:Server(id)`, since there are probably a lot of female clients but probably only a single `Server` with that id. So, you probably want to do this instead:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Server(id);
   ```

   But, even better, if every `Server` has a unique `id` property, you should create a uniqueness constraint (which also automatically creates an index for you):

   ```
   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Server) ASSERT s.id IS UNIQUE;
   ```
2. Currently, neo4j does not use indexes to perform ordering, but there are some [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema_index_queries) that do support that. However, the procedures do not support returning results in descending order, which is what you want. So, if you really need to use indexing for this purpose, a workaround would be to add an extra `minusAge` property to your `Client` nodes that contains the negative value of the `age` property. If you do this, then first create an index:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Client(minusAge);
   ```

   and then use this query:

   ```
   MATCH (s:Server{id:"S1"})<-[:CONNNECTED_TO]-(cl:Client {gender:"F"})
   CALL apoc.index.orderedRange('Client', 'minusAge', -200, 0, false, -1) YIELD node AS c
   RETURN c;
   ```

   The 3rd and 4th parameters of that procedure are for the minimum and maximum values you want to use for matching (against `minusAge`). The 5th parameter should be `false` for your purposes (and is actually currently ignored by the implementation). The last parameter is for the `LIMIT` value, and `-1` means you do not want a limit.

Answer (score 1):

If that is a request you're doing quite frequently, then you might want to write that data out. As you're experiencing, that query can be quite expensive and it won't get better the more clients you get, as in fact, all of the connected nodes have to be retrieved and get a property check/comparison run on them.

As a workaround, you can add another connection to your clients when you modify their age data.

As a suggestion, you can create an Age node and create a MATURE relationship to your oldest clients.

(:Server)<-[:CONNNECTED_TO]-(:Client)-[:MATURE]->(:Age)

You can do this for all the ages, and run queries off the Age nodes (with an indexed/unique age property on the) as needed. If you have 100,000 clients, but only are interested in the top 100 ordered by age, there's no need to get all the clients and order them... It really depends on your use case and client apps.

While this is certainly not a nice pattern, I've seen it work in production and is the only workaround that's been doing well in different production environments that I've seen.

If this answer didn't solve your problem (I'd rather use an age property, too), I hope it gave you at least an idea on what to do next.